When inlining a C function, can an optimizing compiler dereference a pointer more times than explicitly written in the source code?
Consider the following code:
int y = 1;
int* p = &y;

inline int f(int x) {
  return x + x;
}

int g(void) {
  return f(*p);
}

In this code, there is one explicit dereference.
Is a C compiler allowed to compile/optimize this code as, roughly:
int g(void) {
  return *p + *p;
}

That is, while inlining f, can the compiler perform and use two separate accesses to the target memory, as opposed to the single access that was actually written?  Are there specific sections in the C specification that allow or disallow this behavior?  Note that in the example, p is not volatile, and the "optimized" code is at least functionally correct.
(Please note, the question is not "will a compiler do this" or "should a compiler do this", but rather, according to the C specifications, can a compiler do this.  Suppose register spillage makes a second dereference more efficient, or some such thing).
Referencing the C99 specification, I see some possible hints on required handling of parameters.  I wonder about whether "each parameter is assigned the value of the corresponding argument" (6.5.2.2) or "its [the parameter's] identifier is an lvalue" (6.9.1) might prevent this scenario, but that interpretation seems incompatible with some of the common parameter optimizations I have seen.

No, an optimizing compiler cannot do that because that is not an optimization. A deoptimizing compiler could do it, and would be conforming to the C standard as implementing the program with one or two accesses would have the same observable behavior, to the extent it is defined. Why are you referring to C99, which is more than two decades old and which has been superseded by newer versions?

@john - I would rather expect an optimizing compiler to realize that *p is the same as y, and y  is 1. So f(*p) can be replaced by f(1). And then we also know what 1 + 1 is...

@EricPostpischil Any C compiler can do anything it likes as long as it obeys the language specification.

@user207421: The C standard allows a compiler to do anything it likes as long as it conforms. However, the question does not ask about a “C compiler.” It asks about “an optimizing C compiler.” That has two qualifications for the compiler: One, that it is a C compiler, meaning, in this context, that it conforms to the C standard. And two, that it is an optimizing compiler. Turning one memory read into two may conform to the C standard, but it fails to meet the second qualification stated in the question. It is not optimizing.

@EricPostpischil I disagree - suppose some strange architecture has a limited ISA and a register file that is slower than its memory accesses: accessing the same memory twice could be faster than loading it to a register and using it there.  Consider architectures with only one working register, which can be a source or a destination, but not both (common in PIC perhaps) - it can either load then save and load a temporary from the stack, or simply double load from memory, which would be faster.  But it's all really beside the point - the question is really just "is this allowed?".

@johnsmith: It’s a joke, figure it out.

While there is nothing preventing a compiler from reading the location twice (since reads aren't considered side-effects), my experience is that compilers actively avoid doing this. Which is not so strange, since memory reads is a relatively expensive operation on most systems. The normal behavior is rather to read the value into a register and then preserve it in a register from there on - this is true even for severely limited 8-bit MCUs. A sensible compiler for a low-end 8-bitter might look to re-order the code so that all calculations related to one value are done at the same place.

For reference, the technical term for this kind of transformation is inventing loads.

TL;DR: Yes, it's allowed.
It's usually hard to directly answer a question like "is this transformation allowed" by reading the C standard.  In principle, it requires you to look at the rules of the language, and prove that every possible piece of code whose observable behavior is well-defined by the standard would have the same the same observable behavior after the transformation.  Or, if its behavior is unspecified (i.e. there is some set of allowable behaviors), then after the transformation, its behavior would still be within that set.
However, you can reason a little more informally.  If the transformation described here (sometimes called inventing loads) were not valid, there would have to be some code whose well-defined observable behavior would change.  You can get a sense of the legality by coming up with a piece of code whose actual behavior would change, and then ask whether that behavior is in fact defined by the standard.
If two loads were performed, then the only way for the result to be different is if those two loads did not return the same value.  (We can presume that at least one of them would return the same value as the single load in the un-transformed x + x version.)  How can that happen on a real-life machine?  If the load is being performed on ordinary memory (as opposed to a memory-mapped hardware register or something, in which case volatile would be required), then the only way for this to occur is if some other entity in the system performed a store to that address.  Within the C standard, the only defined mechanism for two different entities to access the same memory simultaneously is threads.
So an example of code whose observable behavior could be affected by this transformation would be one where some other thread is simultaneously performing a store to *p.  However, this would constitute a data race, which C explicitly specifies as causing undefined behavior (see 5.1.2.4 p35), and so it's not actually a valid example after all.  If the racey code didn't have well-defined behavior in the first place, then the fact that this transformation changes its behavior isn't any obstruction to the legality of the transformation.
So while this isn't a proof, it's a strong suggestion that this transformation is legal.  And indeed, it's a transformation that real-life compilers will actually do.  Here is an example (godbolt), borrowed from my answer to Which types on a 64-bit computer are naturally atomic in gnu C and gnu C++? -- meaning they have atomic reads, and atomic writes (the answer is emphatically none).


When inlining a C function, can an optimizing compiler dereference a pointer more times than explicitly written in the source code?

Yes, provided that it is not a pointer to a volatile type.
However, with a pointer to an atomic type, the compiler might have to also ensure that the referent could not be modified by another thread between the two dereferences.  (Thanks, @Eric)  Specifically, consider this variation:
_Atomic int y = 1;
_Atomic int *p = &y;

inline int f(int x) {
  return x + x;
}

int g(void) {
  return f(*p);
}

Supposing that p is never reassigned, and that y never takes a value greater than INT_MAX / 2, abstract machine semantics require each evaluation of f(*p) to yield twice some value that y held at some point during that execution of the program.  That could be problematic if that function call were computed as *p + *p, perhaps requiring addition of a lock or similar, but this is context dependent.  However, this is relevant only if a function call result inconsistent with the abstract machine semantics could manifest a change in the observable behavior of the program.  That's not necessarily the case.
If p does not point to an atomic object, however, then conflicting accesses would produce undefined behavior, in which case anything at all that the implentation chooses to do with it is acceptable.

That is, while inlining f, can the compiler perform and use two
separate accesses to the target memory, as opposed to the single
access that was actually written?

Yes, though that would rarely constitute an improvement, so I don't expect any compiler actually to do that.

Are there specific sections in the C
specification that allow or disallow this behavior?

Yes.
As context, C17 5.1.2.3/1:


The semantic descriptions in this International Standard describe the
behavior of an abstract machine in which issues of optimization are
irrelevant.


And the main provision allowing for optimization is C17 5.1.2.3/6:


The least requirements on a conforming implementation are:

Accesses to volatile objects are evaluated strictly according to the rules of the abstract machine.

At program termination, all data written into files shall be identical to the result that execution of the program according to the
abstract semantics would have produced.

The input and output dynamics of interactive devices shall take place as specified in 7.21.3. The intent of these requirements is that
unbuffered or line-buffered output appear as soon as possible, to
ensure that prompting messages actually appear prior to a program
waiting for input.


This is the observable behavior of the program.


Those being the least requirements means that as long as an implementation fulfills those requirements, it can do so by any means it chooses.  That is what enables optimization.

Referencing the C99 specification,

C99 is long since obsolete, though the conclusion is the same for that version.  Since then, there was C11 and the current spec, C17. And C2X is in the final stages of ratification.

I see some possible hints on
required handling of parameters. I wonder about whether "each
parameter is assigned the value of the corresponding argument"
(6.5.2.2) or "its [the parameter's] identifier is an lvalue" (6.9.1)
might prevent this scenario, but that interpretation seems
incompatible with some of the common parameter optimizations I have
seen.

Those details describe the behavior of the abstract machine.  Implementations are not bound to adhere to them, so long as they produce the correct observable behavior.

Atomic objects should be considered too.

I actually did consider them while composing this answer, @EricPostpischil, and as far as I can determine, atomic objects factor in only inasmuch as the semantics of accessing them are part of the semantics of the abstract machine.  C does not attribute volatile-like significance to accesses of non-volatile atomic objects, with respect to the observable behavior of a program.

What happens if p is a pointer to an atomic type and another thread modifies *p between the two reads of *p? In the abstract machine, x + x would produce the sum of one value from reading *p, but implementing two reads could produce a sum of two different values. When the sum is used in subsequent code, the observed behavior may differ.

@EricPostpischil, your "between" is not part of the observable behavior of the program.  When there are multiple observable behaviors consistent with the abstract-machine semantics, an implementation can satisfy the minimum requirement by producing any one of them.  With that said, my initial "yes" should not be taken as saying that arbitrary additional dereferences can be performed.  One could construct more complicated examples where specific cases of doubly- instead of singly-dereferencing could not be correct, but that's not what I take the question to be asking.

OP’s code modified to use an atomic type would have two allowed observable behaviors: One where x + x used the value before another thread modified *p and one where it used the value after another thread modified *p. There is no allowed observable behavior in which it uses two different values.

Thank you, @EricPostpischil, I have added a discussion of the additional considerations surrounding pointers to atomic objects.  That would not preclude the pessimization the OP asks about, but it might require even more of a pessimization (e.g. also inserting a lock around the two dereferences).

This is very helpful.  Suppose the facet of optimization is removed from the question, does that change the answer?  E.g. (excepting the cases of volatile or atomic) would C17 allow "x = *p; return x + x;" to be implemented as "return *p + *p;" ?  (Roughly, would anything in the spec prohibit this duplicate access to a non-volatile variable, or mandate the assignment of *p into separate storage, or etc.).  I have a poor understanding of what (if any) requirements the spec is placing on the internals of the abstract machine - it sounds like correctness is purely defined by observable behavior?

@johnsmith, whether you call it "optimization" is irrelevant. So is whether the implementation behavior actually improves performance or code size.  This answer already describes the (fairly broad) leeway afforded to implementations to behave differently than does the abstract machine in terms of which the language semantics are defined, so long as the same observable behavior is produced.

Unlike languages such as Java which use a relatively weak memory model but nonetheless define the effects of data races as having each read yield old or new data, sometimes chosen arbitrarily, the C Standard characterizes completely waives jurisdiction over how implementations interpret data races.  This allows gcc to translate something like:
unsigned short test(unsigned short *p)
{
    unsigned short temp = *p;
    return temp - (temp >> 15);
}

in a manner that, by adding an extra dereference, avoids the need for a subtraction when targeting the ARM Cortex-M0.  Generated code for the above is equivalent to:
unsigned short test(unsigned short *r0)
{
    unsigned r1 = 0;
    short r2 = *((short*)r0+r1);
    unsigned r3 = *r0;
    r2 >>= 15;
    r3 += r2;
    return (unsinged short)r3;
}

This particular example occurs even when not in-lining a function, but I see no reason to believe the same thing wouln't happen when in-lining functions.
Many compilers' designers have taken the view that any potential optimizations that could be facilitated by being able to add extra dereferencing operations is less useful than Java-style semantic guarantees which make it possible for programs to tolerate benign data races without having to add costly memory barriers to eliminate them, but such sentiment is not shared by the maintainers of gcc, and probably not by clang either.

I know you know this, but C's intended solution to this issue was memory_order_relaxed, which on typical platforms doesn't introduce any "costly memory barriers" and keeps using ordinary load and store instructions.  The main thing that it does is suppress optimizations like the invented loads discussed here.  So you can keep benefiting from them by using non-atomic variables in places where you are sure data races do not occur.  In code where data races can occur, and you just need to make sure they stay "benign", you use atomic objects with memory_order_relaxed.

So in some sense, C does give you the option of a Java-like memory model, if you rewrite your code to do all its memory access with memory_order_relaxed loads and stores - though of course this will make it very verbose and unreadable.  But, unlike Java, it also gives you the option of not having to give up optimizations like invented loads.

@NateEldredge: That would be a solution if there were a mechanism for setting the default.    There are certainly many situations where invented loads are harmless, and in some of those they may facilitate useful optimizations, but make the language unsuitable for the purposes for which it was designed.  Further, support for proper memory semantics shouldn't rely upon support for atomics, which on many platforms would be simply broken.
